# How to sync additional fields in pivot table [Laravel 5]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, synchronization, pivot-table

I need to update my additional filed `user_id` in pivot table... I tried like this:

```
$commet = Comment::find(2);
$commet->likes()->sync([2,'user_id'=>1]);
```

But my filed is updated with `0`. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your sync array isn't right. Try:

```
$commet->likes()->sync(array( 
    1 => array('user_id' => 1),
    2 => array('user_id' => 5),
    ...
));
```

Ie.

```
sync(array( 
    related_id => array('pivot_field' => value),
    ...
));
```