# Many to many relation, laravel sync method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

In my shop application I have 3 tables: products, categories and category_product

products:

```
id | product_id | lang | name
1 | 1 | pl | name
2 | 1 | en | name
```

categories:

```
id | category_id | lang | name
1 | 1 | pl | name
2 | 1 | en | name
```

This is my relation in Product model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_product', 'product_id', 'category_id');
}
```

And now I enter: http://sklep.app/admin/products/2/edit - which is the product of "id" of 2.

When I hit update I want to add records to category_product:

```
category_id | product_id
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

because product_id = 1

instead I receive 3 records

```
1 | 2
2 | 2
3 | 2
```

How can I make my app set product_id to product_id value not the id value.

This is how I add categories to products:

```
$product->categories()->sync($request->categories, (sizeof($request->categories) >= sizeof($product->categories)))
```

Comment: Please post the code that does the updating so we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Damn I forgot :P
`$product->categories()->sync($request->categories, (sizeof($request->categories) >= sizeof($product->categories)))`

Comment: Please check this answer to understand sync method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052390/how-to-sync-additional-fields-in-pivot-table-laravel-5/33052814#33052814

Comment: When posting code as an update to the question, please edit the question and include the code, don't post it in the comments.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of passing the second `detaching` parameter to the `sync` method. Having `->sync($request->categories)` should suffice. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I removed second parameter, and modified passed array like  Kóta Péter posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052390/how-to-sync-additional-fields-in-pivot-table-laravel-5/33052814#33052814 - it worked, thank you for your help :)