# Laravel pivot table with additional fields

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm trying to sync my pivot table with some additional fields. 
But the problem is I don't know how to include these additional fields in my controller. Untill now, I never needed extra fields in pivot table. So I'd just go with `$model->relation->sync(array_of_ids, false)` but cant figure out how to send other fields with the IDs of related model. here is my current code

Model:

```
public function speakers(){

    return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Models\Speaker', "speaker_session_items",
        "session_item_id", "speaker_id")->withPivot('event_id', 'edition_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function store_speakers(Request $request){


    $speakers = $request->input('speaker_id');
    $session_item = SessionItem::findOrFail($request->input("session_item_id"));
    $related = ['event_id' => $request->input('evnet_id'),
                'edition_id' => $request->input('edition_id')];


    $status =  $session_item->speakers()->sync($speakers, $false);

   print_r($status);
}
```

I want to send related data (edition and event as well) how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sync additional fields in pivot table \[Laravel 5\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052390/how-to-sync-additional-fields-in-pivot-table-laravel-5)

Comment: Check docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations, below "Sync Associations", there is a section saying how to pass additional values :)

Comment: Hmm so that I need to parse this array and generate another array. There is no direct way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `save`

```
    $status =  $session_item->speakers()->save($speakers, ['your-additional-attribute' => 'value']);
```

for using `sync`

```
$user->roles()->speakers( [ 
   1 => [ 'attribute' => value ],
   2 => [ 'attribute' => value ],

]);
```

For saving many you can use `saveMany()`

```
    $status =  $session_item->speakers()->saveMany($YourData);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I was thinking to use save. But save requires First argument as object. I'm passing arrays of speaker_ids. Thats why couldn't use this.

Comment: @AhsanShabbir I have updated the answer have a loo. you can use save many